# HTC 10 Multiple Wallpapers

Tags: htc, customization, wallpaper

I've recently got an HTC 10 which is running Android 7.0 and is set up to have 5 pages on the home screen with the HTC sense clock/weather widget on the central page (which is set as the default page).

I was looking for a way to set the home screen wallpaper to have a different image on each page - actually the plan was to have one large wallpaper of 7200px x 2560px (5 screens @ 1440p) split over the pages so it's effectively one large screen.

In the personalisation settings, there is an option to set the home wallpaper to have multiple pages with a different image for each page. However this option so far as I can see only allows for three pages to be defined and gives no option to set which page on the home screen is the centre one. So if I split the wallpaper in 3 pieces (lets call them A, B and C), it ends up displaying on the home screens as `A B C C C`.

Is there any way to change the wallpaper to have 5 different images spread across the 5 pages as `A B C D E`? Alternatively if I'm limited to 3 images, is it possible to change which is considered the centre page (i.e. have it display the images as `A A B C C`)?

I'd prefer not to do it with a separate app, but if not possible is there is free low-weight app that will allow me to do this?

Comment: You could try this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.j4velin.wallpaperChanger